# Is there a way to block nudity?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

As far as I saw, there are naked woman NPCs around the world, spawning in a mansion or in the beach. Also the women inside Vanilla Unicorn are naked too.

The nudity in Vanilla Unicorn can be just discarded by just not going there but the rest is still important, is there a way to block that nudity?

Comment: You are playing a game where you play a **Gangster** and you can beat up hookers to get your money back and shoot a lot of people in the face and you complain about some nipples? Please... That is like playing Hatred and complaining about violence :D

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness getting called a perv when you hit a random spawned naked NPC is not fun at all.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness - I agree wholeheartedly, but some people might have kids that 'want to play daddy's driving game' (as happenned with a friend of mine). Having a way to disable certain content can be a relief, even if they just watch you drive around, but especially if kids know how to get on the computer or game console.

Comment: @Robotnik I wouldn't let my kids play GTA V, because of the violence, would not mind a nipple. Nudity is natural, violence is not. But I guess this a US vs Europe difference.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I may be a bit off topic but... violence is natural also :)). Even though we don't like to admit it.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness how is this a US vs Europe difference when none of the people in the conversation are from the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on PC, modding the game is an option.

Most of my searches found mods that add more nudity but I did find [this mod](http://gtaforums.com/topic/786317-relv-prostitute-and-strip-club-remover/). It claims to make strip clubs inaccessible and removes prostitutes.

Just bear in mind that not all mods are safe and using mods online can get you banned. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Mods are iffy in the community right now as of the late Malware/Key-logger incident found in a series of mods so i would us at own risk.

Comment: @Studoku "Most of my searches found mods that add more nudity" lol.

Comment: @Will309 Added the warning and mentioned mods online.